# convert if((t >= 12) && (t<20)){} to switch

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
var t = 13;

function check() {
    if ((t >= 12) && (t < 20)) {
        alert(true);
    }
}
```

Which I want to convert to switch statement.
I have tried this:

```
function test() {
    switch (t) {
        case (t >= 12) && (t <= 20):
            alert("> 12");
            break;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.I get no errors via the console.Any Ideas?
Actually this question came after comparison with Pascal where i can do this:

```
case t of
12..19://code
end;
```

which is equal to

```
if (t>=12) and (t<=19) then
//code
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp You need to compare to a specific value

Comment: You could, but why? (That's a serious question: to give a good answer, we need to understand your motivation for wanting to do this.)

Comment: Thats because you can't. Tha Case must be followed by a literral (I think).

Comment: @shevski: That's not actually true in JavaScript.

Comment: @cssGEEK you can see my answer, i habe once used this as an hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch doent work like that, you can pass `true` to switch and can use case statement like below

```
switch(true){
            case ((t >= 12) && (t <= 20)):
            alert("> 12");
            break;
        }
```

**Note:** : it is recomended to use if/else as an better option here

**Working Demo :**

```js
var t = 13;

function test(){
        switch(true){
            case ((t >= 12) && (t <= 20)):
            alert("> 12");
            break;
        }
    }

test();
```

Answer (score -2):

Finaly found the answer:

```
function test(){
        switch(true){
            case (t >= 12) && (t <= 20):alert("> 12");
            break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: How is this better than your original formulation?

Comment: Even if it works it is not a recommended operator to use in here.

Comment: It is working.But why downvoting?

Comment: @cssGEEK Don't listen to them. This is perfectly fine. A little verbose over a simple `if` but still perfectly fine.

Comment: @rgthree thanks.Actually my code is working

Comment: @cssGEEK:- Not the downvoter as its not wrong. But people are downvoting it as its a bad approach of solving a simple thing. Downvoting doesnot always means a wrong answer but that people dont like the solution.

Comment: thats an fine solution i think nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @A.B _fine_ is a personal opinion then it may be OK for you but in general: 1) it's not _intended use_ for `switch` then it'll confuse MANY people (they may need to read it 2 or 3 times to understand it). Someone may even don't understand _why_ it works. 2) it's even longer and more prolix than plain `if` so I can't see a reason for it. 3) it's more error prone (not just because absolutely unreadable and counter intuitive but also because it adds a chance to introduce the _missing `break`_ bug). So many drawbacks for which reason? What's the gain?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i agree with your comments and mentioned it in my note also , and i pasted answer before watching this, we both posted at same time

Comment: @A.B just saw it! Please ignore 2nd comment.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes i agree that here switch has no  advantage over if/else but still a way it is to do, but NOT RECOMMENDED

Comment: @A.B absolutely, when I posted first comment I didn't see your answer and I was answering to your comment (_"...nothing wrong with it"_).

Comment: okay :) well your comments have got me downvote, thanks